# Issues in migrating to Live mode PhonePe payment gateway

Tags: google-cloud-functions, payment-gateway, phonepe

I have implemented and integrated phonepe payment gateway in UAT test mode via firebase cloud function but having trouble while migrating to Live mode.
Here is the code -

```
exports.Transaction = onCall({maxInstances:10},async(request)=>{
  const amount = parseFloat(request.data.amount) * 100;
const eventPayload = {
    merchantId: "PGTESTPAYUAT",
    merchantTransactionId: "MT7850590068188108",
    merchantUserId: "MUID123",
    amount: amount,
    redirectUrl: "https://ball24.in",
    redirectMode: "POST",
    callbackUrl: "https://ball24.in",
    mobileNumber: "9999999999",
    paymentInstrument: {
        type: "PAY_PAGE",
    },
};


const encodedPayload = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(eventPayload)).toString("base64");
const saltKey = "099eb0cd-02cf-4e2a-8aca-3e6c6aff0399";
const saltIndex = 1;
const string = encodedPayload + "/pg/v1/pay" + saltKey;
const sha256 = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(string).digest("hex");
const finalXHeader = sha256 + "###" + saltIndex;

const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-VERIFY": finalXHeader,
};

const phonePayUrl = "https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/pg/v1/pay";
const response = await fetch(phonePayUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ request: encodedPayload }),
    headers: headers,
});

const data = await response.json();
// const paymentUrl = data.data.instrumentResponse.redirectInfo.url;

return data;
})
```

Now as soon as i change my credentials to Live ones, and replace host url with production url - https://api.phonepe.com/apis/hermes  .I am getting a error - RESOURCES NOT FOUND.
What should i supposed to do.Can't find anything on internet.Phonepe support also ignoring mails.
Please someone help

The code for UAT sandbox works fine .But not able to migrate to Live mode.Please help

Answer (score 0):

So I have the same issue as well , so the way I resolved it is by using the python SDK instead of the SDK Less approach . Works like a charm .

Answer (score 0):

The production url for payment file will be https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/pg/v1/pay
for redirect page will be https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/pg-sandbox/pg/v1/status/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).